# Alamofire parse and concat JSON in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

Some very basic help needed.. Im new to swift and can't find anywhere a good solution..
I know its very basic basic, but JSON and Swift is harder then I thought :')

```
Alamofire.request("https://website.com/foobar").responseJSON { response in    

    let title = ""
    var message = ""

    if let result = response.result.value {
        let JSON = result as! NSDictionary
        print(JSON) // prints correctly the json

        // {
        //     id: 29,
        //     title: "Foobar",
        //     email: "the@adress.nu",
        //     city: "Berlin",
        //     name: "John Doe",
        //     consumer_iban: null,
        //     updated_at: "2017-04-18 23:47:44"
        // }

        for(key,value) in JSON{
            print("key \(key) value2 \(value)") 
            // this is correct shown too
        }
    }
```

But what I want is the following:

```
if(key == "title") {
    title = value;
}
else {
    message += (\(key): \(value))
}
```

But that concatting and refering to a key as string doensn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
let title = JSON["title"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, you throw away the type information

```
let JSON = result as! [String:Any]
```

The problem are the missing double quotes, you need those for String Interpolation.

```
if key == "title" {
    title = value
}
else {
    message += "\(key): \(value)"
}
```

Btw: parentheses around the `if` condition and semicolons are not needed in Swift